# How to change the GUI of the application?

Tags: c, winapi, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Skin an Win32 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216917/how-to-skin-an-win32-application)

I'm trying to learn to design a application, but I'm stuck.

For a example, how would I code/get this kind GUI ( Background image, navigation, the engineering icon in the up left corner, styled minimize and quit icons ... etc ) in C/Win32API as represented on that picture?

[image: BF3 C# GUI]
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific thing that you tried and it didn't work? Your question is way too broad to be answered in a simple form expected from StackOverflow

Comment: It is a borderless window with lotsa code in the WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT message handlers.  Always a bug factory, getting the headers misaligned with the columns is pretty typical when you have to do *everything*.

Comment: @HansPassant I assumed they were centered :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a web page. Have you considered writing it in HTML and CSS instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "skinning".

See this article for example: [(Flipcode)](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Win32_Window_Skinning.shtml)

All you have to do is to create the `HBITMAP` object (load it from Resource or from File) and the use the `SelectObject` to choose it as a background.

Comment: "the plague that kills windows" makes no sense. It's just hyperbole; skinning hasn't "killed" windows. Your answer would be better without that statement. If you think skinning is bad, that's ok, but explain your opinion rather than try to be dramatic.

Comment: It's all about consistency, which cannot be expressed but can be felt. A while back I also loved custom interfaces, but now I use only the default settings. OK, "it's been emotional" :)

Comment: Skinning has not killed Windows [yet], but it has killed individual applications. I kill applications with custom skins all the time. The uninstaller is the most important part of a skinned app. The WinAMP folks learned this years ago. I don't understand why everyone else is so slow to the party. Don't copy what Microsoft is doing, they're just thrashing around desperately trying to beat Apple in the "cool factor" department, rather than just making solid software that works. It's not their finest moment.