# Visual Studio 2010 Dialog Editor produces Win95 themed controls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, user-interface, aero

I've just started using Visual Studio 2010's Dialog Editor and the first thing I noticed was that the controls I can add all have the Windows 95 style and not the Window Vista/7 Aero style.

I suspect that maybe only MFC has Aero style controls, but I can't test this since I really do not want to use MFC (this is supposed to be a super lightweight program).

Is there anything I can do to make Dialog boxes with Aero style controls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programming In C + Win API: How To Get Windows 7 Look For Controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663091/programming-in-c-win-api-how-to-get-windows-7-look-for-controls/5663284#5663284)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that your application includes a [comctl32 v6 manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx) to enable visual styles.

The simple way to do this is to add the following to your code:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```