# VS 2010 Windows Form App - One Form has a different visual style - why?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010

I am building my first "real" VB Window Forms Application (I'm a "traditional programmer") and my application has perhaps half a dozen forms.

On execution all of these forms have the Windows 10 visual style (eg: grey on white max/min/close buttons at top right)... except for 1 form, which seems to be rendering in Win XP style (eg: Blue and red button style).

I have checked that "Enable XP Visual Styles" is UNClicked in the Project Properties, but this one form stubbornly refused to change.

I have a number of my forms that also appear in "XP style" in the VS Designer, but execute fine.

I suspect I may have enabled/disabled the "XP Visual Styles" option a couple of times, and perhaps initially created some forms when this was in different states... although I have no idea if this would have been the cause.

I really want this one form to be like all the others...

any ideas please? I am using VB in VS2010 (a bit old, but what I have to hand)

As I am quite new to VB so tell me what I can provide to help..

Many thanks,

Comment: It may not be entirely clear exactly what you are talking about (screenshots would help), but to [theme your app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5663091/11683) you set that tick, not clear it.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? It seems like one of them may be getting opened with `Form.Show()` rather than `Form.ShowDialog()`, perhaps?

Comment: David, you are exactly right! The single form appearing differently is indeed using Show() whereas the others are all ShowDialog(). There is no reason for me doing this, so I have changed it, but I will have to read up on the reason why later...  Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

David's comment has solved my immediate issue:

The single form appearing differently is indeed using Show() whereas the others are all ShowDialog(). There is no reason for me doing this, so I have changed it.