# How do I force GetStockObject to return the correct font

Tags: windows, fonts, gdi

This image shows the basic problem:

[image]

Let me explain what this shows.  At the very top are the buttons from the properties box of JPsoft's TCC/LE - the OK and Cancel buttons have the correct font.

The "360 - Time check delay" and the OK / Cancel buttons immediately below are from an application I'm working on.  On every other system, this dialog displays with a non-bold font, but on my main system (Windows 10) it shows in bold.  The `FONT` statement for the dialog in the `.rc` file is as follows:

```
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
```

which is something I've been using for the past 20 years or so, and it's never done this to me before.

The lines of text at the bottom that start with the date / time stamps are logging lines from this app, they are again bold only on this one Windows 10 machine, and are created using a font gained from this line:

```
HFONT hFont = GetStockObject(ANS_VAR_FONT);
```

What adds to the confusion is that the title bar and menu of the app show with the correct font, it's only text rendered via WM_PAINT i.e. the logging,  and dialog boxes that use the wrong font.

I'm completely at my wits end about this.  What possible things could I be doing wrong that would cause this problem with just one program on just one computer?

Comment: See [Enabling Visual Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5663091/4603670) Recommended dialog font is Segoe UI size 9 for Windows Vista and higher.

Comment: That fixed the dialog box, but the main display is still corrupted.  I could probably fix that by explicitly creating the font, but that really defeats the point of GetStockObject().

Comment: Rather ironically, ignoring the advice in the remarks section of the MSDN page for `GetStockObject()` provided a solution for the main display.  According to that page "It is not recommended that you use DEFAULT_GUI_FONT or SYSTEM_FONT to obtain the font used by dialogs and windows;"  However, switching the GetStockObject() call to use `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` solved the problem.

Comment: You can use `HFONT hfont = SendMessage(hwhd_dialog, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);` if you are painting in dialog.

Comment: I'm trying to do it "by the book" as much as possible.  WM_PAINT is strictly limited to painting in the main application window.  I let the dialogs do their own thing, I just call DialogBox() and let GDI take care of it all for me.  As noted earlier, the code I'm dealing with is about 20 years old, hence the reason it uses the aged "MS Sans Serif".  While working it, I learned long ago to avoid doing anything clever, and instead just let the OS and the API take care of things for me.  Doing so has helped simplify things tremendously.

Comment: Okay, if that fits your needs. Otherwise you are not supposed to use `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT`, and I don't know what is `ANS_VAR_FONT` [What are SYSTEM_FONT and DEFAULT_GUI_FONT?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050707-00/?p=35013)